# How to find out all the points where a function is not differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across a question wherein I was asked to find out where all the function $\left|x^2 - 5x+ 6\right|$ is differentiable. I plotted the graph of the function and I was able to find out that the above function isn't differentiable at $2$ and $3$.

Now without plotting the graph of the same, how can I find out the points where the above function isn't differentiable (or any other function).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser The OP has told us what they tried, and wants another method.

Answer (score 3):

You should know that $x^2- 5x+ 6$, a polynomial, is differentiable for all x and that |x| is x if x>0 and -x if x< 0 so is differentiable for all x **except** x= 0.  Putting those together, $|x^2- 5x+ 6|$ is differentiable for all x **except** where $x^2- 5x+ 6= (x- 3)(x- 2)= 0$.

$|x^2- 5x+ 6|$ for all x except x= 2 and x= 3.

Comment: Though one has to be careful. While it's true that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then their composition is also differentiable, we can't conclude that the composition isn't differentiable just because one of the functions isn't differentiable. Take $|x^2|$, for instance, which is differentiable everywhere, even though the inner function is $0$ at $x=0$ and $|\cdot|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general method for this kind of question. To decide where a particular given function is differentiable you have to examine that function. Sketching a graph is a natural first step and usually leads to a correct answer.

In this particular case you can reason backwards from what you discovered to see why the answer is what it is. The points you found are the roots of the quadratic. The absolute value function has a corner at the origin that leads to the corners at those roots. Everywhere else the absolute value only affects the sign of a part of the quadratic and doesn't destroy the derivative.

Comment: Yes. I have edited my question. Thanks for pointing it out